# Change DataTemplate Child Dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListView which has a column for checkboxes. When a checkbox is checked, I want to swap it out with a [progress ring](https://mahapps.com/docs/controls/progressring). Then, when the activity I want is completed, I can hide the progress ring and display the checked checkbox. Is this possible? A DataTemplate only seems to accept one child

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="StatusHeader" Header="Status" Width="50">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Margin="5, 0" IsChecked="{Binding loaded}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **DataTemplate** contains only one child, but this child can be without problem a Container such as a Grid or a StackPanel, which will contain your elements:

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="StatusHeader" Header="Status" Width="50">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox Margin="5, 0" IsChecked="{Binding loaded}" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
                <ProgressBar />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Seems to work, but is there any way to place the ProgressRing exactly on top of the CheckBox?

Comment: You mean overlapping both? You can use a Grid instead of a StackPanel. But if you collapse one of the two elements, even a StackPanel should work.

Comment: There's just one issue I noticed. I am trying to change the visibility of the controls when I press the checkbox. It seems that changing the visibility has no effect. https://i.imgur.com/WroHF0m.png  & https://i.imgur.com/0cZ3el6.png Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you to use a converter and to Bind the visibility of your Progress Control to the state of the Checkbox, like in this example: https://riptutorial.com/wpf/example/7309/convert-a-boolean-to-visibility-value

Comment: Of course you can use a Binding of your ViewModel instead (IsChecked in your case)